# Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase.get_Name()'

Tags: entity-framework-6, abp

in my project i use ef core 6*. version.
and AspNetCoreHero.EntityFrameworkCore.AuditTrail.dll for  Auditing.
is it compatible with ef core 6.
when call commit method getting this error: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase.get_Name()'
how can it be fixed? thank you

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i update EFCORE nugget to 6.0.8 - it worked with me after update.

Answer (score 1):

AspNetCoreHero.EntityFrameworkCore.AuditTrail.dll is not  compatible with .net 6 [click here](https://github.com/aspnetcorehero/EntityFrameworkCore.AuditTrail/issues/2) to see

Comment: I updated the library for .NET 6  and put it in the comments :)